# npm i not working? npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, npm

My npm install seems to have stopped working out of nowhere, regardless of if i do npm i or npm install I keep getting an error saying npm ERR! Unexpected token '.' The other npm commands seem to be working perfectly but I can't install any modules because of this error. I'm using npm 8.7.0 and node v14.18.1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I could find and what worked for me was completely removing and unisntalling everything to do with nodejs and npm from my laptop. I then reinstalled it back with no issues and am able to use the command now.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in one of the answers, try deleting the node_modules folder and **package.lock.json**. Use

> sudo npm install

And if that doesn't work, what I would suggest is that you use yarn. If you don't know what yarn is, it's just a package manager like node.
You can install yarn by using the following command:

> npm install -g yarn

After this make sure all the node modules and package.lock.json is deleted. Now run the command

> yarn install

Hopefully, this will fix your issue.

Comment: author wants fix with npm and you are saying to use yarn? If `npm install` is not working how can one use `npm install -g yarn`

Comment: His npm install is not installing packages, in most of these cases npm is working fine and could be used to install other packages.

Comment: Ok that's exciting but can you share any valid proof/documentation